# Creating a Product Tree from Excel BOM

Tags: excel, vba

I have a standard Bill of Materials in Excel. The hierarchy is defined by the product level in column 1, column 2 and 3 are part number and product name respectively.

Example:

```
+---+--------+--------------------+
| 1 |   2    |         3          |
+---+--------+--------------------+
| 0 | 111111 | TOP LEVEL ASSEMBLY |
|   |        |                    |
| 1 | 123456 | ABC                |
|   |        |                    |
| 2 | 454444 | DEF                |
|   |        |                    |
| 2 | 533433 | GFG                |
|   |        |                    |
| 3 | 342333 | DFD                |
|   |        |                    |
| 3 | 234232 | FFD                |
|   |        |                    |
| 4 | 234343 | DSD                |
|   |        |                    |
| 3 | 322222 | DDS                |
|   |        |                    |
| 1 | 343433 | DFD                |
+---+--------+--------------------+
```

If this was structured, it would look like this:

```
0 111111 TOP LEVEL ASSEMBLY
      1 123456 ABC
            2 454444 DEF
            2 533433 GFG
                 3 342333 DFD
                 3 234232 FFD
                       4 234343 DSD
                 3 322222 DDS
      1 343433 DFD
```

I am looking to have a macro create an actual family tree structure that would show the dependency of these items in Visio (with boxes and logical connections). So in this case, it would look something like this (except in block/arrow format).

```
                              **111111 TOP LEVEL ASSEMBLY**
               123456 ABC                                     1 343433 DFD
  454444 DEF         533433 GFG
                  342333 DFD    234232 FFD         322222 DDS
                                      234343 DSD
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: why you use there tag 'visio' ?

Comment: Can you show us what code you've written to try to solve this?

Comment: I would like to create a block diagram ("Family tree") in Visio